# How do javafx multithreading execute sequentially?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I don't know if there are any other good ways to achieve the results I want, thank you.

I have a requirement, according to the URL, create multiple webview threads, and execute them in order, such as thread execution, then trigger thread two execution, and so on, I use the synchronized (lobject) method, but in JAVAfx encountered a problem, the code is as follows:

```
public class LockObject {

    public int orderNum = 1;
    public final static int MaxValue=9;

    public LockObject(int orderNum){
        this.orderNum = orderNum;
    }
}
```

```
public class DownloadThread extends Thread{

    private LockObject lobject;
    private int printNum =0;
    private String url;

    public DownloadThread(LockObject lobject,int printNum,String url){
        this.lobject=lobject;
        this.printNum = printNum;
        this.url = url;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lobject){
            while(lobject.orderNum <= lobject.MaxValue){
                if(lobject.orderNum == printNum){
                    System.out.print(printNum);
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            webView.getEngine().load(url);
                            webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                                @Override
                                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) {
                                    if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                                        try {
                                            //xxxxx 

                                            // java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
                                            lobject.notifyAll();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    lobject.orderNum++;
                    if(lobject.orderNum==downloadThreads.length){
                        saveCsvFile(goodCSVS);
                    }
                    //lobject.notifyAll();  is ok
                }else{
                    try {
                        lobject.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Place of call

```
private DownloadThread[] downloadThreads;
LockObject lobject = new LockObject(1);
downloadThreads = new DownloadThread[tableView.getItems().size()];
for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
    UrlModel item = tableView.getItems().get(i);
    downloadThreads[i] = new DownloadThread(lobject,tableView.getItems().size()-i,item.getLink());
    downloadThreads[i].start();
}
```

Calling lobject.notifyAll() in the run method in Platform.runLater will report an IllegalMonitorStateException. After the address is processed, I want to wake up the next thread to execute.

Comment: What is the point of creating multiple threads when all work is supposed to be done one by one sequentially? Why not use a single thread instead?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to execute multiple tasks in order, there's no need to create multiple threads. Just using a single thread will guarantee the next task only executes after the previous one has completed. You should also consider using a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) instead of synchronizing on an object.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
try {
    for (UrlModel model : tableView.getItems()) {
        executor.submit(() -> {
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                engine.load(model.getLink())
                engine.getLoadWorker().runningProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
                    if (!nv) {
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                });
            });
            latch.await();
            // do whatever needs to happen after the WebEngine finishes loading
            return null; // using #submit(Callable) and Callable needs to return something
        });
    }
} finally {
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Some notes:

- You may want to avoid creating the `ExecutorService` if the table has no items to process. That is, assuming you don't reuse the same `ExecutorService` every time.
- If you reuse the `ExecutorService`, don't call `shutdown()`.
- This `ExecutorService` uses non-daemon threads. You can customize this by supplying a `ThreadFactory` that creates daemon threads.
- I added a listener to the `Worker#running` property instead of the `status` property to make it easier to ensure `countDown()` is invoked no matter the terminal status of the load (i.e. whether it's `SUCCEEDED`, `CANCELLED` or `FAILED`).
- You may want to remove the the listener added to the `Worker`'s property when it's finished. You can do this by using an anonymous class (rather than the lambda expression I used) and calling `obs.removeListener(this)` inside the `changed` method, where `obs` is the `ObservableValue` argument.

Comment: I thought that a single thread executor would make a good answer. Glad you took the time to write it down :-)